# How to use Linear Discriminant Analysis for projection in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, dimensionality-reduction

Is it possible to project a multidimensional data to a 2D map using LDA? It seems that the tool Matlab provided does not provide such functions...

Thanks for reply. My data now is having 6 classes, so does it mean that if I have 6 classes, I can only reduce it to 5 dimensions? Or can it be done in a similar way with PCA, which takes the top 2 eigenvalues, and use these 2 for projection? The PCA does not quite work for my problem as an unsupervised approach, so I am wondering if LDA might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LDA isn't really meant for dimensionality-reduction strictly speaking, especially in the cases where all your data belongs to one class.  It's meant to come up with a single linear projection that is the most discriminative between between two classes.  Thus, there's no real natural way to do this using LDA.

If your data all belongs to the same class, then you might be interested more in [PCA (Principcal Component Analysis)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), which gives you the most important directions for the data ranked in order of importance.  Other methods exist as well [like ISOMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomap) (as mentioned by EMS in the comments) or [self-organizing maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map).

As a side note, LDA can help you reduce dimensionality if you know that you have multi-class data.  It can help you reduce dimensionality down to `k-1` dimensions if you have `k`-class data, but you didn't mention that this is the case.

EDIT:  Credit goes to @EMS for helping to clarify this answer.

Comment: Once you compute the best projection from some set of training data, you can apply that projection to any newly collected data to reduce its dimensionality. I don't know what the generalization properties of this will be, but it's certainly a valid dimensionality reduction scheme (though probably inaccurate).

Comment: Sure, that single linear component will be one such dimension, but I don't know of a generalization to LDA that comes up with more than one (and I've looked),  hence my first sentence.

Comment: That's surprising. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) lists dimensionality reduction among the first applications of LDA, and in particular, multi-class LDA is [described as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Multiclass_LDA) finding a (k-1)-dimensional subspace through N-dimensional data space that best separates the k different classes. LDA generalizes straightforwardly to finding a k-dimensional plane through N-dimensional data, where k < N.

Comment: As an aside, the [Isomap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomap) is an alternative to PCA type methods that attempts to preserve the manifold distance between data points, instead of Euclidean distance. There may be variants of Isomap that attempt to project manifold distances down in a way that handles between- and within-class scatter optimally, but I'm not familiar with them. Isomap may be too complicated for this problem, but it's good to know what the options are.

Comment: @EMS, the OP didn't mention anything about having multi-class (or even two class for that matter) data.  I made the logical stretch that he was interested in two class data since he mentioned LDA, but LDA is typically not used for dimensionality reduction in one-class problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by one-class problem, but I think I understand what you were saying in general now and I agree. If it's just a two-class problem, then the linear decision boundary between them will be a point (or possibly points) along a single line, and in that case LDA would not be a good way to take a high dimensional data set down to 2 dimensions.

Comment: By one-class problem I mean, a dataset assumed to all be of the same class.  Anyway, I think the OP is more interested in ISOMAP, self-organizing maps, or PCA (or something similar).  Maybe I should edit the answer to incorporate our comments to make the answer more clear.

Comment: I think maybe just add a comment explaining that the dimension that LDA allows you to reduce down to depends on how many classes you have. If you have k classes, it helps construct a k-1 dimensional linear space for discriminating those classes. You don't specify some arbitrary smaller dimension that you wish for with LDA, as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I have tried using PCA for the task actually, but the PCA approach does not work quite well. The energy of the first two principle components is not very high. And as I can have the data labelled here, I thought the supervised LDA might help.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right two principal components?